# Forge viewer - fitToView when running locally and loading local sourced model

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to ensure that when a 3d model is loaded into the viewer it should always orient the model in isometric view and then fit to view.

I have tried the viewer.fitToView(null, null, true) method as well as viewer.fitToView(model) but no success.

This is what I currently have:

```js
var options = {   
                      
              env : 'Local',     
              
            };         
        
            var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('ADViewer'));

            Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options,function() {               
                 
                
             if (showDocumentBrowser) {
                    //file is 2D so load document browser extension
                    
            viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser');                                
                 
                    // for sheet metal pdf drawings display page 2 first
                    if(sDisplayFlag == "sm") {                          
                            
                        viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.PDF').then(function() {
                        // URL parameter `page` will override value passed to loadModel
                        viewer.loadModel(sFileName, { page: 2 });               
                            
                       });
                       }
                       else {
                          
                          viewer.loadModel(sFileName);
                          
                       }
                 }else
                 {                   
                   //file is 3D model. Need to add code here to orient model in isometric view and then fit to view                 
                    
                    viewer.loadModel(sFileName);                        
                    
                 }          
                        
            viewer.setTheme('light-theme');
            viewer.start(options);                  

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between local or official mode while using fitToview.

The function declaration of the [Viewer3D#fitToview](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#fittoview-objectids-model-immediate) is `fitToView(objectIds, model, immediate)`, so the ways you're using are incorrect.

```js
// Make the camera focus on one object
const selSet = viewer.getSelection();
viewer.fitToView(selSet[0]);

// Make the camera zoom out
viewer.fitToView();
```